# Turn SQL data which is separated by comma to SQL "in" instructions

Tags: sql, sql-server

First Statement :

```
Select GroupMember
FROM Group
```

Result:
                         Los Angeles,San Diego
                         (it is a string)

Second Statement :

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Store_Information 
 WHERE Store_Name IN ('Los Angeles', 'San Diego');
```

How to turn Los Angeles,San Diego(one data) to IN ('Los Angeles', 'San Diego')?

Comment: you gave both the question and the answer :)

Comment: But "Select GroupMember FROM Group " is just a string ex."Los Angeles,San Diego"

Comment: Not a very good data model to use. IMHO it's better to change the data model than to get a solution for this bogus model.

Answer (score 3):

Use inner query

```
SELECT * FROM Store_Information
WHERE Store_Name IN (Select GroupMember FROM Group)
```

Comment: But "Select GroupMember FROM Group" result is not like ('Los Angeles', 'San Diego')

Comment: it doesn't  matter @Molly inner query return single Column.so in statement check whether store_name in that column or not

Comment: What if "Los Angeles,San Diego" just a string not seperate string?

Comment: @Molly i think you pretty much confuse with your Question .please explain briefly..

Comment: I want Using comma separated value strings in SQL IN clauses

Answer (score 1):

you can write a query as

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
Store_Information WHERE Store_Name IN (
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String   
       FROM  (SELECT  CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(groupname, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' 
                             AS XML) AS groupname       
               FROM  Group) 
       AS A 
CROSS APPLY groupname.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do it with a subquery, a better way is with a join:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Store_Information s
JOIN Group g ON g.GroupMember = s.Store_Name
```

Comment: Why is a join better? Duplicate rows in the result if `Store_Name` is not unique perhaps?

Comment: is it ok to join with name field ??i know it' possible but i don't think it is feasible ..

Comment: @MikaelEriksson there will be duplicate rows if `GroupNember` is not unique - in this case add `DISTINCT` keyword after `SELECT`. Regarding performance, many modern databases will convert the `IN` version to the `JOIN` version, but some may not. The join is preferred because it allows merge join access plan.

Comment: @Dhaval it is OK - joining by non-key fields is one of the strengths of RDBMS. If an index is defined on `Group(GroupMember)` it will perform well.

Comment: Ah, yes of course `GroupNember`. I got the tables mixed up. The part about the merge join not being used for `IN` is new to me. Looks like I need to do some testing on that one.

Comment: Ok, now I have checked and in SQL Server you **will** get a merge join using `IN` if the optimizer thinks is appropriate. The rewrite with `DISTINCT` when using a join can give you the same plan as with `IN` but only if you fetch a column with a unique constraint/primary key. If you don't, SQL Server will have to do the job of removing duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Look like the

```
Select GroupMember
FROM Group
```

only return 1 line which is Los Angeles,San Diego

So you can use this

```
SELECT * FROM Store_Information
WHERE Store_Name IN (Select ''' + REPLACE(GroupMember,',',''',''') + ''' FROM Group)
```

1. append ' in front of Los
2. replace , -> ','
3. append ' at the end of Diego